# Drupal Migration Database Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal

I have a Drupal Website source code directory and SQL file for a current Drupal Website. I have set up a blank website (we have our own server) and new database using PHPMyAdmin for that server. I have added the SQL file to the db and updated sites > default > settings.php with the new username, password and db name.

However, when  trying to load the website I get an error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in DatabaseConnection->__construct() (line 307 of D:\wwwroot\xxxxxxx\includes\database\database.inc).
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in DatabaseConnection->__construct() (line 307 of D:\wwwroot\xxxxxxx\includes\database\database.inc).
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in DatabaseConnection->__construct() (line 307 of D:\wwwroot\xxxxxxx\includes\database\database.inc).
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in DatabaseConnection->__construct() (line 307 of D:\wwwroot\xxxxxxx\includes\database\database.inc).
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of D:\wwwroot\xxxxxxx\includes\lock.inc).
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in DatabaseConnection->__construct() (line 307 of D:\wwwroot\xxxxxxx\includes\database\database.inc).
```

Do I need to alter host information in either my created db or the settings.php file? Because I haven't changed anything yet?

Comment: seems like that your server can't resolve the db server name: is it spelled right?

Answer (score 0):

Double check `settings.php` for correctness, especially the host name